# Android Native platform configuration

Tags: android, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, flutter

## **[UPDATE]**

Flutter can only support release APK for either 32 or 64 bit, but **not both**

After testing on Galaxy Note 3,API Level 19 on firebase testLabs which was crashing.
I solved the problem (at least for now) by adding

```
release {
    ndk{
         abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"    // not working for "armeabi", "x86"  
       }
 }
```

Then I forced generating APK to arm as shown:

```
flutter build apk --release --target-platform android-arm
```

and it worked!

Gradle property can be set to android-arm(default) or android-arm64 **not both**

---

## **[Question]**

How can I configure my code to run in all native platforms like
"armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi-v8a", "x86","x86_64", "mips" .. and other architecture. (need to support all platform)

The reason for this is I want to upload an update version for an existing app in google play that has "Native platform = none", So my app must have the same platform dependencies to not lose users and not only target "armeabi-v7a"

I followed the android docs here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits like this:

```
splits {
    // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi-v8a", "x86","x86_64", "mips", "mips64"
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

but It failed to build APKs and shows an error:
**Gradle build failed to produce an Android package.**
when I run `flutter build apk --release` .. Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is correct for generating multiple apk artifacts in typical android builds with C++ code, one for each architecture. However flutter is still not able to build for most of the architectures you're defining.

```
flutter build apk -h

. . .
    --target-platform         [android-arm (default), android-arm64]
```

Notably missing x86 and x86_64.

For practical purposes flutter is covering almost all physical devices, since there's no new phones using x86 for quite a while now, and even years ago they were few. The biggest downside to it is that we're unable to run production builds on emulators.